# select condition from cdef$ where rowid=:1 query elapsed time is more

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle11g

In Db trace, there is a query taking long time.Can some one explain what it means.Seems this is very generic oracle query and not involved with my custom tables.

```
select condition from cdef$ where rowid=:1;
```

Found the same query in multiple places in trc files(DB trace) and one among all have huge amount of elapsed time. So, what will be the solution to avoid taking such a long time. Am using 11g version oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that is an example of Oracle's recursive SQL, the statements it runs against the data dictionary to support our application SQL. That particular statement is the query Oracle runs to get the Search Condition of a CHECK constraint.  If you are inserting or updating rows in tables with check constraints you will see it a lot.

The actual statement shouldn't take too long to run, so it is unlikely to be the source of a performance problem.  Unless you are running lots of insert statements with hard-coded values.  Oracle will run that query every time it parses a fresh insert or update statement.  That will get expensive if you're not using bind variables.